# How can I add points on a plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a list of points that I want to a plot, but I can't figure out how to do it with `Epilog`.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Gammaconst = 1.67; 
Pa = 975.452; Pb = 975.452; Pc = 384.269; Pd = 384.269;
Ta = 355; Tb = 355; Tc = 295; Td = 295;
R = 8.3144; n = 0.000137;
V1 = 4.97*(10^-6); V2 = 2.736*(10^-5); V3 = 2.902*(10^-5); V4 = 
 6.63*(10^-6);
P[V_, T_] := n*R*T/V;
Plot [{P[V, T = 355], P[V, T = 295]}, {V, 0.000005, 0.00003
  }, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Volume (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(3\)]\))", 
   "Pressure (Pa)"},
 Epilog -> {Line[{{V1, P[V1, 355]}, {V4, P[V4, 295]}}],
   Line[{{V3, P[V3, 295]}, {V2, P[V2, 355]}}]}]
Plot[{{V1, 101325 - Pa}, {V2, 101325 - Pb}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]]
```

I get a nice graph and I want to mark a few points on it to show where they are. After the first `Plot` command is a second plot containing the points I was testing with. I get an error mesage that says

> "PLot called with one argument, two expected."

I am now utterly convinced that the people who write error messages don't want anyone to understand them.

Sorry, but this is just frustrating as all getout because the whole thing should take an hour and I have been messing with this all bloody day.

Comment: Your points are [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6kL70.png) for me. Looks weird, but is it what you want?

Comment: Cose. I was trying to illustrate the points that I measured in a lab against a "perfect" carnot cycle, and show the difference. It's possible I wasn't seeing them, but did you arrange the code the same way? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is clear. `Plot` requires two arguments: the first being an expression the gives a function of one variable to be plotted and the second being a range specification for that variable. Your second `Plot` expression provides it with neither.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use `Point` within `Epilog`:

```
Plot[{P[V, T = 355], P[V, T = 295]}, {V, 0.000005, 0.00003}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure (Pa)"},
  Epilog -> {       
    Line[{{V1, P[V1, 355]}, {V4, P[V4, 295]}}], 
    Line[{{V3, P[V3, 295]}, {V2, P[V2, 355]}}],
    Point /@ {{V1, 101325 - Pa}, {V2, 101325 - Pb}}},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 101325}}]
```

Or you can plot two different things and `Show` them:

```
p = Plot[{P[V, T = 355], P[V, T = 295]}, {V, 0.000005, 0.00003}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Volume", "Pressure (Pa)"}, 
  Epilog -> {        
    Line[{{V1, P[V1, 355]}, {V4, P[V4, 295]}}], 
    Line[{{V3, P[V3, 295]}, {V2, P[V2, 355]}}]
    },
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 101325}}];
lp = ListPlot[{{V1, 101325 - Pa}, {V2, 101325 - Pb}}];
Show[{p, lp}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks this was one of those thing that was really frustrating and should illustrate why if you like coding yo need a high frustration tolerance. :-)

Comment: oh, the /@ -- is that the same as a bracket or something? I have never seen that.

Comment: ok, by the way when I tried adding a third point i get an error message again. I tried fixing th ebrackets and now the range is too small again (like it doesn't see the Plotrange command arrrrggh

Comment: **Surgeon General's Warning:** Accepting without upvoting causes halitosis and genital warts

Comment: ok I think i am getting this. But man this has to be the most frustrting thing I have ever used

Comment: last question: where would I put pointsize if i wnt the points to be bigger?

Comment: i'm copying the format you have for epilog. be aware I know NOTHING about mathematica. I'm at the "I just want to get this done" stage. I just want to make the points bigger.

Comment: `{..,Line[],PointSize@.1,Point/@..}`

Comment: @Öskå Now _you_ made me LOL :)

Comment: Thanks @Öskå this was a big help and you have prevented someone from flinging a laptop out a window :-)